# Work with Cydia Store API

Tags: ios, udid, cydia

I made a payed app for Cydia. I like to verify if the user officially bought the application. I already figured out, that there is a [Cydia Store API](http://test.saurik.com/cydia-packagers/api2%20v06-print.pdf) but I have several issues with it. Does anyone ever used it or is there an alternative to verify if the user bought it? The API is using the UDID, which has been made unaccessable in iOS 7, however Cydia and several other application can access the UDID. I figured out that you can calculate the UDID with SHA1 hash of serial + IMEI + wifiMac + bluetoothMac and with the SHA1 hash of serial + ECID + wifiMac + bluetoothMac on the Verizon iPhone 4. I can get the Serial number, but I am not able to get the IMEI, ECID, WiFi MAC and the Bluetooth MAC. Is there a methode to get the UDID on iOS 7?

I really appreciate your help!

**Edit**

---

After a long night I figured out how to get the UDID of an device on iOS 7. Its fairly easy.

1. Add "libMobileGestalt.dlib" and "libMobileGestaltExtensions.dlib" to your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
2. Download [MobileGestalt.h](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/MobileGestalt/MobileGestalt.h) and add it to your project
3. Copy to get the UDID of the device:

   CFStringRef value =MGCopyAnswer(kMGUniqueDeviceID);
   NSString *udid = (__bridge NSString *)(value);
   CFRelease(value);

---

Now I just have to know how to correctly calculate the signature. This is my current way.

```
NSString *signature = [self hmacsha1:[[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[dataString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""].uppercaseString key:@"abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789"];
    signature = [self toBase64String:signature];
    signature = [[[signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"_"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@""];
```

But somehow the signature is wrong, so the response is: `signature=THE_SIGNATURE&error=invalide+signature+MY_QUERY`

And I don't know why, because I am hmac_sha1 hashing the text with a key, this is my hashing function:

```
+(NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)text key:(NSString *)secret {
    const char *cKey  = [secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: I have this same question and will be very thankful to anyone who has a valid answer!

Comment: @Shredder2794 I edited the answer, I already know how to get the UDID, now I just have to work out the rest, may you help me?

Comment: I am planning on working on this later tonight so I will let you know what I find out. Thanks for the info on the UDID!

Comment: @Shredder2794 Have you figured something out yet?

Comment: I emailed Optimo(BigBoss repo) about it and he said that you need to put your dev private key up on a server and then make a request to your server to create the HMAC-SHA1 key. This makes sense as if you included your dev key in code it would be very simple for a hacker to use a decompiler and find it. I'm just going to make a simple PHP script to do this. All of the other info that is required is pretty simple to create. Also, Optimo said that this: http://test.saurik.com/cydia-packagers/API4%2520v10.pdf is actually the newest version of the API guide. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Shredder2794 Oh, then I assume that you can use the php script Sauric provides on the webserver: http://test.saurik.com/cydia-packagers/refserver6.php.txt right? (I am not good in PHP yet…)

Comment: I believe that's right. At the moment though I am perusing other things as I came to the conclusion that most people pirating my software are to poor to buy it anyway, so I will just let them have it.

Comment: I don't think that most of the people are poor, they just want to "hack" something, so they are cool or to save money. But I think that the users should pay for a good application, because we developers spend month on it, we hire designers, buy or design artwork… And "poor" people can contact me, and I will register them for free or they can get the trail version with limited functions.